Compare Numerical and analytical solution for a simple case!
I wanted to check this equation for analytical and numerical solution but they don't meet each other??
 Clear["Global`*"]
 eqn1 = {(x''[t]/x[t]) + ((3 γ)/2 - 1) (x'[t]/x[t])^2 - (3 γ*f)/2 == 0};
 eqn2 = {y'[t] + (3 γ)/2 y[t]^2 - (3 γ*f)/2 == 0};
 (*y[t]=x'[t]/x[t]*)

 sola = DSolve[eqn2, y[t], t]
 (*Boundary condition says y[1]=1 for Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1] then \-(3  \.[Gamma])/2+ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[f]]/Sqrt[f] *)

 sola2 = DSolve[x'[t]/x[t] == Sqrt[f] Tanh[Sqrt[f]/ 2 (3 t γ + (2 ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[f]])/Sqrt[f] - 3 γ)],x[t], t]
 soln = NDSolve[{eqn1 /. {γ -> 1, f -> 0.69}, x[1] == 1, x'[1] == 1}, x, {t, 0.01, 5}];
 f = 0.69; γ = 1;
 Plot[{x'[t]/x[t] /. soln,
       x[t] /. soln, Sqrt[f] Tanh[Sqrt[f]/ 2 (3 t γ + 2/Sqrt[f] ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[f]] - 3 γ)], 
       Cosh[3/2 Sqrt[f] (-1 + t) γ + ArcTanh[Sqrt[f]]]^((2/3)/γ)},
      {t, 0.0, 5},
      Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"y Numerical", "x Numerical", "y Analytical", "x Analytical"}, Scaled[{0.7, 0.7}]],
      PlotRange -> {{0.35, 2}, {0.001, 3}}]

